Empty Character issue when using InnerHTML
I create DOM Inner HTML with this code below:
var popupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'popup-vhcmap');
tablepopupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('table','table table-infopopup',popupVhc1);
trpopupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('tr','',tablepopupVhc1);
tdiconpopupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('td','col-1 align-midle bg-popup-gre',trpopupVhc1);
infoiconpopupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('i','bi bi-car-front-fill text-icon-popup',tdiconpopupVhc1);
tdcontentpopupVhc1 = L.DomUtil.create('td','col-6 td-content-popup',trpopupVhc1);

tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += '<b>B 8384 UCR</b><br>';
tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += 'Moving - 84 Kph - 25<sup>o</sup><br>';
tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += '24-09-2024 20:38:32';

div.popup-vhcmap {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #6d6d6d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.table-infopopup {
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
}

td.bg-popup-gre {
  background-color: #03b420;
  text-align: center;
}

td.td-content-popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

i.text-icon-popup {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

I have found issue about spacing (empty character) in my result as picture below:

What's wrong? If I remove tag b or sup, empty spacing will be removed, but this isn't the result that I want.

What I want is like this
B 8384 UCR
Moving- 84 Kph - 25o
24-09-2024 20:38:32
not:
....B 8384 UCR
Moving- 84 Kph - 25 o
24-09-2024 20:38:32
also not:
B 8384 UCR
Moving- 84 Kph - 25o
24-09-2024 20:38:32
PS:
I tried with add "span" like this:
tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += '<span><b>B 8384 UCR</b></span><br>';
tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += '<span>Moving - 84 Kph - 25<sup>o</sup></span><br>';
tdcontentpopupVhc1.innerHTML += '<span>24-09-2024 20:38:32</span>'

and the result is below (IT'S WORK)

CLOSED with add "span" tag as code above.

could it be padding or margin perhaps?

what is L.DomUtil ?

Use the dom inspector in devtools to see the spacing/padding/margins around various html elements.

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using your browser inspector.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources

Can we have a sample code snippet to check this? Then it will easy to check.

Issue solved with adding "span" tag.
See my body question

Hello, please do not answer your own question if you don't give the answer in it. Maybe an edit is suffisent or add the answer in this answer.

Oh, sorry. I'm new on this forum and still confused with FAQ rules...Thanks for remind. But, the issue above has solve with adding  tag.

No problem, maybe you can explain a little bit more than just adding "span". Maybe with showing your final code where you have solve your problem ? You also can accept your own answer if you want. Have a nice day.
